# Webmock equivalent for curl commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rspec

I've written a controller function that runs a curl command to send a message to a 3rd party service.  I'd like to test this function to confirm my message was sent.  However, when I use Webmock, it does not block the command.  What can I do to validate that the message was sent in an rspec test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) which allows me to send custom, `curl` style web requests in ruby.  I can also stub calls with it.  The rspec test content looks like:

```
  it 'correctly prepares a new Typhoeus request and runs it' do
    Typhoeus::Request.should_receive(:new).with(<request>).and_call_original
    Typhoeus::Request.any_instance.should_receive(:run).and_call_original
    object.method
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use ruby to make the HTTP call, or you could wrap the curl command in a module on which you could set an expectation:

```
module Curl
  def self.perform(url)
    `curl -s "#{url}"`
  end
end

Curl.stub(perform: 'http response')
perform_some_action
expect(Curl).to have_received(:perform).with(the_url)
```